# Tests ran in gitlab-ci fail as Postgres can't been seen

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, gitlab-ci, cookiecutter-django

Tests using gitlab-ci in docker fail as the `Postgres` service in not accessible.

In my dev environment, I run tests successfully with: `$docker-compose -f local.yaml run web py.test`

But in gitlab, the command `- docker run --env-file=.env_dev $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE py.test -p no:sugar` in the gitlab-ci.yaml file fails with:

```
9bfe10de3baf: Pull complete
a137c036644b: Pull complete
8ad45b31cc3c: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:0897b57e12bd2bd63bdf3d9473fb73a150dc4f20cc3440822136ca511417762b
Status: Downloaded newer image for registry.gitlab.com/myaccount/myapp:gitlab_ci
$ docker run --env-file=.env $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE py.test -p no:sugar
Postgres is unavailable - sleeping
Postgres is unavailable - sleeping
Postgres is unavailable - sleeping
Postgres is unavailable - sleeping
Postgres is unavailable - sleeping
```

Basically, it cannot see the Postgres service. The text `Postgres is unavailable - sleeping` comes from an entrypoint.sh file in the `Dockerfile`

Below are some relevant files:

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  - test

variables:
  CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME


before_script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE --file compose/local/django/Dockerfile .
    - docker push $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE

pytest:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
    - docker run --env-file=.env_dev $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE py.test -p no:sugar
  when: on_success
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
# ... other configs here
ENTRYPOINT ["compose/local/django/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh:**

```
# ..... other configs here

export DATABASE_URL=postgres://$POSTGRES_USER:$POSTGRES_PASSWORD@postgres:5432/$POSTGRES_USER

function postgres_ready(){
python << END
import sys
import psycopg2
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="$POSTGRES_USER", user="$POSTGRES_USER", password="$POSTGRES_PASSWORD", host="postgres")
except psycopg2.OperationalError:
    sys.exit(-1)
sys.exit(0)
END
}

until postgres_ready; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "Postgres is up - continuing..."
exec $cmd
```

The above setup & configuration is inspired by [django-cookie-cutter](https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment-with-docker.html)

Comment: A silly question - have you passed in the environmental variables to gitlab-ci and sh script? On mobile, so might not seeing it.

Comment: Yes. The environment variables are correctly passed to gitlab-ci. Proof of that is that the Build phase works... Am not sure though what you mean about passing variables to the sh script

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: Not yet. Any ideas?